# Azure Custom Vision: ONNX gives different results from that of the portal/API

Tags: image-processing, azure-cognitive-services, ml.net, microsoft-custom-vision

I am using azure custom vision(customvision.ai) where i have upload around 100 images and have trained the model to detect face mask.

When i try to test in customvision portal it gives correct result but when i try to get the confidence/probability in the visual code where i have exported as onnx model and using ML.Net framework it is not giving correct result. For the same image working in customvision.ai is not working in vs code.

Also when i use the prediction url & prediction key in postman it gives multiple probablity, is there extra parameter i need to pass to get accurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the ONNX model and the accuracy:**

Your image should be:

- Resized to 224 x 224
- In BGR format (converted if necessary)

This information is stated in the [Cognitive Services ONNX Custom Vision Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-onnx-customvision-sample) repo referenced in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/custom-vision-onnx-windows-ml) of the Custom Vision Service

That's why you're getting different results, the portal/API ensures the proper things gets done in the background!

You can apply resizing and cropping using your own application logic to ensure the proper thing gets done as well when using ONNX model.

You can use [automatic code generation with mlgen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/mlgen) if you are working with a ONNX model and are unsure what variable types to utilize, this utility will generate the correct types.

I do recommend using any of the following samples to avoid any confusion at the beginning,  or any other sample that you find useful:

- [cognitive-services-onnx-customvision-sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-onnx-customvision-sample)
- [ObjectDetection-Onnx](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/ObjectDetection-Onnx)

**Regarding Postman and multiple probabilities:**

You receive the probabilities for the labels you have, you can narrow them down using your own application logic to show only the label with the highest accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the response.i am using the same reference example ObjectDetection-Onnx, actually i am using images of size 416*416. The code works for few images of 416*416 but doesnt work for few images for the same size, let me try to reduce the size to 224*224 and will check.